# How to add a JPanel as a component to another class via an event listener in MainFrame

Tags: java, swing, events

I am quite new to Java and am still not familiar with hierarchies, my code consists of one main JFrame that I want to act as the controller of all the Panels. I have a ToolBar class that extends as a JPanel and then EditorPanel that extends as a JPanel as well and I simply want to add another panel called IntroPanel on my EditorPanel using a button in my ToolBar.

When I try to add the IntroPanel directly from my MainFrame it works but doesn't work when I trigger it via an eventlistener.

What could be the problem in it?

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private EditorPanel editorPanel;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    public MainFrame() {
        super("Ankanaya");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        toolbar = new Toolbar();
        editorPanel = new EditorPanel();

        toolbar.setEditorListener(new EditorListener() {

            public void editorEventOccured(EditorEvent ev) {
                setIntroPanel(editorPanel);
            }
        });

        //editorPanel.add(new IntroPanel());

        add(editorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setSize(900, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }


    public void setIntroPanel(EditorPanel panel) {
        EditorPanel editorPanel = panel;
        editorPanel.add(new IntroPanel());

    }

}
```

---

```
package gui;

import java.util.EventObject;

public class EditorEvent extends EventObject{

    public EditorEvent(Object source) { 

        super(source);//here source is going to be toolbar
    }

}
```

---

```
package gui;

import java.util.EventListener;

public interface EditorListener extends EventListener {

    public void editorEventOccured(EditorEvent ev);


}
```

---

```
package gui;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Toolbar extends JPanel{

    private JButton introButton;
    private EditorListener editorListener;
    private MainFrame mainframe;

    public Toolbar() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        introButton = new JButton("Add Intro");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        add(introButton);//adding to the layout

        introButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EditorEvent ev = new EditorEvent(this);

                if(editorListener != null) {
                        editorListener.editorEventOccured(ev);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setEditorListener(EditorListener listener) {
        this.editorListener = listener;
    }

}
```

---

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class EditorPanel extends JPanel{


    public EditorPanel() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 


    }



}
```

---

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class IntroPanel extends JPanel{

    private JTextField text1;
    private JTextField text2;
    private JTextField text3;
    private JTextField text4;



    public IntroPanel() {

        text1 = new JTextField(2);
        text2 = new JTextField(2);
        text3 = new JTextField(2);
        text4 = new JTextField(2);


        add(text1);
        add(text2);
        add(text3);
        add(text4);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));

        setBackground(Color.black);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `revalidate` to the end of `setIntroPanel`, I think. AWT wont relayout and repaint without being told.